# Accessing ISP subnet resources?

Tags: routing, subnet

This is my first question here so I don't know if I would supply all the relevant and required information.

The situation:

I have IPTV and Internet from the same provider. I managed to get the links for all IPTV channels that the STB device has in it's memory. I wanted to stop using the device and start using KODI (XBMC). The main reason is that the device needs another remote and the ISP doesn't have a device that supports HDMI-CEC.

What I have gathered so far is that there are 3 main servers for streaming:
10.5.0.4
10.5.0.3
10.5.0.2
There is also a DHCP server at 10.5.0.1. In order to get an IP address for this subnet I have to present a specific MAC address that belongs to the device and also a vendor-id in the DHCP request (option 60). I can however use the allocated ip address of the device and the MAC address, disconnect the device and then get access to the streams from the server.

So far, so good.

The problem:

I want to be able to connect KODI to my local network and actually stream everything through the local network. *This would mean that KODI can directly stream the IPTV streams (from 10.5.0.2-4) while maintaining a LAN IP address of the type 192.168.1.xxx* Not having to use 2 LAN cards in order to get IPTV and local videos from the network. I was thinking that the best way would be to have a static route.

I added the route to DD-WRT:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         thor.onlinedire 0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 vlan2
10.5.0.0        10.5.0.1        255.255.255.0   UG    0      0        0 vlan2
93.152.128.0    *               255.255.128.0   U     0      0        0 vlan2
127.0.0.0       *               255.0.0.0       U     0      0        0 lo
169.254.0.0     *               255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 br0
192.168.1.0     *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 br0
```

And this is the trace route:

```
traceroute to 10.5.0.3 (10.5.0.3), 30 hops max, 38 byte packets
 1  thor.onlinedirect.bg (93.152.128.1)  0.875 ms  0.341 ms  0.324 ms
 2  thor.onlinedirectbg (93.152.178.1)  0.682 ms  0.717 ms  0.592 ms
 3  178.132.84.202 (178.132.84.202)  2.708 ms  2.944 ms  2.829 ms
 4  *  *  *
 5  *  *  *
 6  *
```

But even from the router I can't ping any of the servers. So my question is how would I make this to work? Am I forgetting something?

EDIT:

I was thinking that adding a static route to the router would allow me to forward the request to the specific ISP subnet and access it.

Network diagram[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, it is not clear what you are asking. Please edit your question and it will automatically start a reopen vote. You may find our [Question Checklist](http://meta.networkengineering.stackexchange.com/q/292/33) helpful to improve your question. For starters, could you provide a network diagram? What do you mean by "stream through the local network" and why do you think a static route would be the solution? More specifically, why that static route?

Comment: Okay. Can we move the question or should I repost it?